# Open link with jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm totally not good at jQuery, but this is getting hilarious. Searching the web for 2 hours, trying to found how to open a link with jQuery, without any result.

I have tried this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#default

What I want is from the example above, change this code (and get it to work):

```
<a href="#">An anchor</a>
```

to

```
<a href="my_site.php">An anchor</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').attr('href', 'my_site.php');
```

however I advise you to give you link an id so it does not do this to ALL links, so

```
<a id="linkness" href="#" >An anchor</a>

$('#linkness').attr('href', 'my_site.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a[href='#']").attr('href', 'my_site.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

That page adds an event handler to the buttons' click events.  That event handler returns `false` which is a technique for telling the browser "don't actually follow this link when someone clicks it."  This prevents the link from behaving the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('a[href=#]').attr('href', 'my_site.php');
```

If you have more than one anchor tag on your page, you'll probably want a better selector than `a[href=#]`, but you get the idea.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/WGPYp/